# Gamenet accounting

Tags: networking, accounting

we have 5 systems and 5 XBOXs and we want to connecting these devices together for making a game net, I have used GamePort as accounting system, but one problem of this software is that we can join only clients that have GamePort client edition in fact it is useful for computers,
my problem is for XBOXs.
how can I join XBOXs to gameport software.
is there a software for accounting gamenet with computers and some XBOXs?
**Thanks in your advise**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it appears that http://www.interactivestudio.sk/, the people who made the Gameport accounting client/server system for use in internet cafes and such... doesn't exist any more.  It is actually [available](http://whois.marcaria.com/domain-whois/europe/slovakia-domain-sk/).  So, it's not being developed at all, anymore.

One of the last major reports on it, and security vulnerabilities within it, [was back in 2004](http://www.securiteam.com/windowsntfocus/6V00K00C1G.html).

There does not appear to be a client written to be installed on an XBox anywhere out there.  So, with no further development on the software and no client for the environment you want to use, you are pretty much out of luck.

Don't be fooled into thinking that it's still supported, just because you can find some download sites that still have it available.

Comment: for now what's your offer for my situation?

Comment: barring having to contact Microsoft to arrange for a Licensing Agreement to legally use their console in a commercial venture... you could use timers, and have an attendant keep track of who has to get off a console when their time is up.  There does not appear to be Game Time Accounting software available for the XBox